# Build a latest table from a history table using max()

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, a mls_history table, and a mls table.  The mls_history table has every record uploaded to the system, and the mls table is a subset of mls_history, only containing the latest status date (stat_date).

For example:

```
MLS_HISTORY:

mlsnum | stat_date
-------------------
1      | 2013-01-04
2      | 2013-01-08
1      | 2013-04-09
1      |

MLS:

mlsnum | stat_date
-------------------
1      | 2013-04-09
2      | 2013-01-08
```

I want one insert/select query (if possible?) that grabs the max stat_date for each mlsnum, and stores it in the mls table.

There are a few examples already on stackoverflow, but almost all of them allow for multiple records if stat_dates are the same.  I want this to only return 1 record, even if 2 meet the max criteria.

To further complicate things, there are no serial columns, so no unique id, so I can't just say "in case of a tie, pick the one with the max id".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mls                -- assuming it's empty
SELECT DISTINCT ON (mlsnum) *
FROM   mls_history
ORDER  BY mlsnum, stat_date DESC;
```

Select *exactly* 1 row per `mlsnum` with the latest `stat_date`.

Details and explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 1):

In this case a mundane `group by` does the job

```
select mlsnum, max(stat_date)
from mls_history
group by mlsnum
```

The (very handy) `distinct on` used in [@Erwin`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23313656/131874) is Postgresql only and it is a bit harder to understand complicating future maintenance.

Comment: I chose Erwin's answer only because I don't believe I can use this for my insert/select.  Partially my fault in my explanation, but in my case, I actually have more than two columns in my real table (200 columns to be exact), so group by mlsnum fails if I select more than mlsnum, max(stat_date).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. You should choose the best answer for the question you asked not for the one you should have asked